# Ajax replacing entire page, not just the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page with an Ajax call that is supposed to replace a content div. When the link is clicked, though, the entire page is replaced with the content div, instead of it just replacing the text it was supposed to.  Any thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#gnav a').click(function () {
        var page = this.hash.substr(1);
        $('#contents').html("");
        $('#content_wrapper').block();

        $.get(page +'.php', function(gotHtml){
            $('#contents').html(gotHtml);
            $('#content_wrapper').unblock();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="contents" style="height:1200px; width: 620px">
    <!-- all html here that should be replaced-->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code to the Ajax part that doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  I think the Ajax is OK itself, but I'm not so sure about the selectors...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the block() and unblock() methods? Even so, those selectors should probably be $('#contents_wrapper') to match the id in the markup.

Comment: blockUI is a plugin that grays out the page while the ajax is loading and gives you a nice little message of 'please wait' while the div loads.

Comment: Hmm. I'm guessing in the script src for the blockUI plugin, the url should be https://github.com/malsup/blockui/raw/master/jquery.blockUI.js to link to the actual javascript instead of the Github tree.

I would focus a bit on cleaning up the code in its entirety, and you might run into your AJAX bug during that process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use $.load()?

```
$(function () {
    $('#gnav a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#contents').load(this.hash.substr(1) +'.php')
    });
});
```